# Tomcat´s server.xml dynamic configuration

Tags: tomcat, server.xml

My web application uses the same database configuration as the application XYZ. I have a resource declaration for a context in server.xml, so I have a duplicated configuration (once for web application and once for application XYZ). How can I read some 'external' values into server.xml? For example:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDB" username="${user}" password="${pwd}" url="${url}" ...
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how this is a duplication? I would understand it if user/pass/url were the same for both applications (i.e. the entire `<resource>` tag), but this is not true in your case. They're actually different! Can you please elaborate a bit more about the "duplication" you're talking about?

Comment: But I sad: "same database configuration", so user/pass/url are the same.

Comment: Then just define a global datasource?

Comment: Another application is not a web application. That is why I want to share database config in a unique and separate file.

Comment: Are you using Ant by any chance to build your web application?  If so I might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - you can't do this with tomcat configuration. Also, specific for server.xml, the only way to reload it is to restart the server.

If you need the datasource only within one web application, then a way to do it is by using the spring framework and [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html).

Another way might be to inherit from tomcat's [StandardHost](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardHost.html) and [StandardContext](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContext.html) and do some custom parsing.